# No response for https request after configuring Tomcat for https

Tags: rest, tomcat, https

I have configured Tomcat v7.0 server with SSL as mentioned in the below link.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration

I didn't receive any response for request sent through REST client for my REST service. 
URL: https://localhost:8443/context/getData

However there is successful response if I hit with the below URL.
http://localhost:8080/context/getData

Please suggest if I am missing something to get this working.

Below is server.xml connector entry.

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="C:\Users\Srivignesh\.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Below is web.xml entry.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>Jersey RESTful Application</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
     <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Also when I type below URL in browser, it shows certificate invalid error indicating that https is successfully configured.

https://localhost:8443/

Comment: What do you mean by `didn't receive any response` there must be a response like Request Tiimeout, Connection Reset, Server Error(505) etch. also It would be helpful if you share your `server.xml` .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the server.xml entry in the question. There was no response sent back to REST client as I already mentioned. No error codes, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working after correcting 2 mistakes.
1. server.xml corresponding to the correct TOMCAT server was available in the workspace folder itself. This needs to be updated for connector entry.
2. REST service that is used, required a JSON input.